# Макет меняется при повороте экрана на эмуляторе, но не на реальном устройстве

Tags: android, recyclerview, orientation

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией: необходимо, чтобы при изменении ориентации устройства столбцов `RecyclerView` становилось не 2, а 4. На эмуляторе все работает правильно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот `RecyclerView` в портретной ориентации. Поворачиваем эмулятор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите, появляется кнопка обновить и по нажатию на нее столбцов становится 4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако когда запускаю проект на своем устройстве, после поворота остаются все те же 2 столбца и кнопки обновить нету.

Вот как реализую поворот в коде:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        previewImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
    }
    else {
        previewImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    }
}
```

И в манифест добавил строку для этой активности:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: а после смены не надо адаптер обновлять?

Answer (score 1):

Иконка переворота (а не обновить) которая появляется, появилась только в 9 андройде. На реальном девайсе (если не 9 андройд) ее может не быть. Скорее всего у вас на телефоне отключен автоповорот экрана, поэтому не триггерится...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть другие варианты решения. В моем случае у меня может быть несколько ViewHolder и для каждого из них я могу указать разное количество.

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        gridlayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 4)

        gridlayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return when (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                    EnumPHOTOS.PHOTOS.id -> if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                       2 else 1
                    else -> 4
                }
            }
        }
        recyclerView.layoutManager = gridlayoutManager
    }
```