# Подогнать размер ячеек RecyclerView под ширину экрана

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать в RecyclerView, чтобы в вертикальном положении экрана, влезало 3 квадратных recyclerview_item, а в горизонтальном 4 квадратных recyclerview_item, и соответсвенно размеры квадратов подгонялись динамически?

recyclerview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="1dp"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#75adc2"/>

</RelativeLayout>



//Открыть галерею
public void Button_open_gallery() {
    RL_frGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // data to populate the RecyclerView with
    String[] data = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"};

    // set up the RecyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
    int numberOfColumns = calculateNoOfColumns(this, 180);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data);
    //adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




}

public static int calculateNoOfColumns(Context context, float columnWidthDp) { // For example columnWidthdp=180
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float screenWidthDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    int noOfColumns = (int) (screenWidthDp / columnWidthDp + 0.5); // +0.5 for correct rounding to int.
    return noOfColumns;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем точный вопрос. Горизонтальный или вертикальный RV? Возможно вам нужен GridLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout

Answer (score 1):

Отвечал на этот вопрос сегодня
[Поворот экрана RecyclerView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950457/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5/950464#950464)

В вашем случае может быть так. В данном случае у меня используется несколько ViewHolder.  И у item, который тип `EnumPHOTOS.PHOTOS` будет будет выводиться 3 горизонтальной и 4 в вертикальной. Для других типов, будет выводиться 1

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    gridlayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 12)

    gridlayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return when (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                EnumPHOTOS.PHOTOS.id -> if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                   4 else 3
                else -> 12
            }
        }
    }
    recyclerView.layoutManager = gridlayoutManager
}
```